# Sum and average total columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm using this query to find duplicate dates but not sure how to sum each duplicate dates, average it and remove duplicate dates.

DB Schema

```
date_time
datapoint_1
datapoint_2
```

SQL Query

```
SELECT date_time, COUNT(date_time)
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY date_time
HAVING COUNT(date_time) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(date_time)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new table to replace the old one. That is easier and might even perform better:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable2 (LIKE mytable);

INSERT INTO mytable2 (date_time, datapoint_1, datapoint_2)
SELECT m.date_time, avg(m.datapoint_1), avg(m.datapoint_2)
FROM mytable AS m
GROUP BY m.date_time;
```

Then you can drop `mytable` and rename `mytable2` to replace it.

To prevent new rows from creating duplicates, you could change the way you insert data:

```
-- to keep track of counts
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD numval integer DEFAULT 1;

-- to prevent duplicates
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD UNIQUE (date_time);

-- to insert new rows
INSERT INTO mytable (date_time, datapoint_1, datapoint_2)
VALUES ('2021-06-30', 42.0, -34.9)
ON CONFLICT (date_time)
DO UPDATE SET numval = mytable.numval + 1,
              datapoint_1 = mytable.datapoint_1 + excluded.datapoint_1,
              datapoint_2 = mytable.datapoint_2 + excluded.datapoint_2;

-- to select the averages
SELECT date_time,
       datapoint_1 / numval AS datapoint_1,
       datapoint_2 / numval AS datapoint_2
FROM mytable;
```

Comment: I cant use this kind of solution because the data keep changing if there is new data coming in. there must be duplication of data.

Comment: Then change the data ingestion, e.g. by using `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` to aggregate the data as you insert rows.

Comment: the duplication must be happen because there will be a script to readjust the date. after that I need to find the duplicate data with same dates and remove it

Answer (score 0):

When you use `GROUP BY` you can also use aggregate functions to reduce multiple lines to a single one (`COUNT`, that you used is one of such functions). In your case the query would be:

```
SELECT date_time, avg(datapoint_1), avg(datapoint_2)
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY date_time
```

For every distinct `date_time` you will get a single row with the average of `datapoint_1` and `datapoint_2`.

Comment: but how to remove duplicate dates and replace with average data?

Comment: You don't need to *remove* duplicate columns: using `GROUP BY` and `avg()` you will get *one single* column for every `date_time` with the average of the other data.

Comment: You mean you want to `DELETE` the duplicate rows from the table?